# Recursion Array Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

This is a beginner question. I am new to recursive functions and can't quickly work out why the code below works but when trying to do all of this in one line, it doesn't in React.

```
// Works:
generateDummyData(num, sentences) {
    sentences.push(randomSentence());
    return num === 1 ? sentences : this.generateDummyData(num-1, sentences);
}

// Doesn't Work:
generateDummyData(num, sentences) {
    return num === 1 ? sentences : this.generateDummyData(num-1, sentences.push(randomSentence()));
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

### Update

A nice work around would be to create a new array and spread the old data into the new one. I don't know if performance and memory would be impacted by something like that but it does work.

```js
generateDummyData(num, sentences) {
    return num === 1 ? sentences : this.generateDummyData(num-1, [...sentences, randomSentence()]));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sentences.push(randomSentence())` does not return the array but returns the new length of the array.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

[Source: MDN push doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
var test = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log(test.push("d"));
```

Comment: Updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the result of `push` in your second example. The [result of push is the length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value), not the array itself. Something like this should work:

```
return num === 1 ? 
    sentences : 
    this.generateDummyData(
       num - 1, sentences.push(randomSentence()) && sentences
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) , it returns

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

So in your example you are not passing `sequences` to your next method call, but sequences length.

That is why those two methods are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Push returns the size of the array after adding elements to it and hence when you use it while passing data to the function, it passes the returned value instead of the array value after pushing value. You should make use of concat instead

```
generateDummyData(num, sentences) {
    return num === 1 ? sentences : this.generateDummyData(num-1, sentences.concat([randomSentence()]));
}
```